# Certain Product Attributes Not Displaying On Category Page

Tags: magento-1.9, category, product-attribute

I'm just working on a project of mine and I can't seem to get certain product attributes to display on the front end of the category page.

This is the current configuration for one of the custom attributes that wont work:

[image: Attribute]

I then have this block of PHP:

```
     <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                            <?php  if ( !($_product->getData('has_options') || $_product->isGrouped()) ) :  ?>
                                <a href="/book-testdrive" class="addtocart" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_product->getAttributeText('registration')); ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Book Test Drive') ?>"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-road"></i><span>&nbsp;<?php echo $this->__('Book Test Drive') ?></span></a>
                            <?php else : ?>
                                <a href="/book-testdrive" class="addtocart" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_product->getAttributeText('registration')); ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Book Test Drive') ?>"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-road"></i><span>&nbsp;<?php echo $this->__('Book Test Drive') ?></span></a>
                                <a href='/book-testdrive' style='display:none'>Options</a>
                            <?php endif;?>
      <?php else: ?>
```

This is replacing the add to bag button with a `<a>` tag that links to another page.

As you can see I am trying to put the `registration` attribute within a value on the `<a>` tag:

```
value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_product->getAttributeText('registration')); ?>"
```

However the attribute never gets placed into the value, I've also tried adding it to any part of the page and it wont display.

Any idea where I am going wrong with this?

It must be because the attribute is a custom one that I have made however I'm unsure exactly what is causing the issue.

Thanks, Nick

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong function, `getAttributeText` isn't for text attributes

```
/**
 * Get attribute text by its code
 *
 * @param $attributeCode Code of the attribute
 * @return string
 */
public function getAttributeText($attributeCode)
{
    return $this->getResource()
        ->getAttribute($attributeCode)
            ->getSource()
                ->getOptionText($this->getData($attributeCode));
}
```

A text attribute will just get its value loaded with the product, so `$_product->getRegistration()` or `$_product->getData('registration')` etc should all work.

You have use `->getData()` to get an array of everything loaded into the object, and `(string) $collection->getSelect()` to see the sql query that generated your collection if you want to make sure everything is loaded properly